# Android: Mysql, php, json, http and security

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, api

I'm quite new to the Android and Java world; I'm trying to develop an app that need to get and insert information in a database.
I searched on the net, and I found that the best solution is to use HTTP connection using PHP files with Jsons outputs as an interface between the application and the Mysql Db.

However, I can't figure out how to 'secure' everything.
Example:
To change the nickname of an user i connect my app to a php page with this code:

```
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
nicknameChange($id,$nickname);
function nicknameChange($id,$nickname){
global $mysqli;
$sql = "UPDATE users SET nickname = ? WHERE id = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('si',$nickname,$id); 
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Via post i pass the id of the user that wanna change nickname and the new nickname, how can i be sure that no one will 'manipulate' that page passing to it ids of other users to change their nickname?
I read on the Net that an HTTPS connection may solve the problem, is that enough?

Answer (score 0):

In your client (android) and in server(php) you need use a key like 'API KEY'

In server

```
$message = 'Access denied';
$checkApi = false;
if(function_exists('apache_request_headers')){
    if(apache_request_headers()['Authorization'] == '2d30ff242f8650954bfe8c993f084f4f')
        $checkApi = true;
}
```

or

```
if(isset($_SERVER["Authorization"]) && $_SERVER["Authorization"] == '2d30ff242f8650954bfe8c993f084f4f'){
    $checkApi = true;
}
```

Client: in your request you will put string '2d30ff242f8650954bfe8c993f084f4f' with key 'Authorization' to Header request.

This is a private key!

Comment: If someone with reverse-engineering get the key '2d30ff242f8650954bfe8c993f084f4f' from the application he would be able to build a fake app to bypass this, is this statement correct?

Comment: So you can generate it from your android application id (ex: authen.example.com) and in your request you send a private + app id ( by method)